# How to determine total derivative of a multidimensional function with 2 components, when using Lagrange multipliers to determine the critical points?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

First of all, $g(x,y,z)= \{{(x^2+y+z),(x-3y+z^5)}\}$ is the constraint given, for which the total derivate has to be determined.

Btw the function given was $f(x,y,z)= x^4+y^2+z^3$ which is not a vector.

In my opinion I need to calculate $dg/dx + dg/dy + dg/dz$, but these 2 components confuse me because I either receive a vector or it doesn't work, but my professor received a single component equation system. I don't understand how he arrives at this
single component equation system after using the Lagrangrange multiplier method.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean to say we want to find the critical points of $f$ on the set $\{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y + z = x-3y+z^5 = 0\}$? If $g_1(x,y,z) = x^2 + y + z,g_2(x,y,z)=x-3y+z^5$ are the components of $g$ the multivariate lagrange  theorem says an optimal point $(x,y,z)$ must satisfy $\nabla f = \lambda_1 \nabla g_1 +\lambda_2 \nabla g_2$ for $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}.$